# MySQL Workbench 6 passwords with special characters

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

How can I get MySQL Workbench 6 to allow me to create a connection where the password contains special characters?  In particular, the password might contain ^, #, {, }, (, ), [, or ].

When I attempt to use the password as-is, I get an "Access denied for user" error.  When I connect to the DB through command line, as long as I surround the password in single quotes I can connect successfully.

I have tried saving my password in the vault surrounded in single and double quotes, but I still cannot connect to the DB.  I have tried using the escape character "\" before every special character in the password, but that did not work.

I have not found any documentation on MySQL's site for this.

**NOTE**: This appears to be an issue specific to Windows (I'm using Windows 10).

Any ideas?

Comment: And you can connect with such passwords using the command line client? I don't see why MySQL Workbench wouldn't accept passwords with symbols (they are all in the ANSI range, even). There must be something else that prevents proper use.

Comment: Yes, I can connect through command line as long as I quote my password.

Comment: Created MySQL Bug report https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87840